# django rest framework no authentication no permission

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

---

I want to access api without any authentication or permission in django rest framework. To achieve this whenever I am having following setting I end up in error.

Setting:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError at /endpoints/

'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9900/endponint/?format=api
Django Version:     1.8.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Exception Location:     /home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in __init__, line 480
Python Executable:  /home/user/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.0
Python Path:    

['/home/user/Projects/test/new',
 '/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 5 Aug 2015 13:46:35 +0000

Endpoint:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:9900/endpoint/?format=api

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  85.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  456.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  453.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  43.             serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get_serializer
  109.         return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  480.                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])

Exception Type: TypeError at /endpoints/
Exception Value: 'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

But when I am using following setting it works but asking for authentication credentials.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Please let me know how to access rest apis without any credentials.

I am running with django 1.8 djangorestframework 3.1

Comment: Need to see your view code for '/environments/'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use following settings for DJR:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',),
}
```

[AllowAny](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany) permission isn't really need, but I think it'll good practice to explicitly define that behavior in configuration.

Comment: It's not working as well, throwing Type Error, 'context' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Hmm, I tested this configuration with code from DRF tutorial and it's works fine with authenticated and unauthenticated users, providing all info in "request" object.

Comment: Yes it works. Apologises, there was a problem in my code.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use [`AllowAny`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany) permission in the permission classes and keep  authentication classes as empty in the DRF settings.**

Doing this will allow unrestricted access to the API without any authentication schemes.

As per DRF docs on `AllowAny` permission class:

> The `AllowAny` permission class will allow unrestricted access,
>   regardless of if the request was authenticated or unauthenticated.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...    
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (), # no authentication classes
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny', # will allow unrestricted access
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this error can happen when using a model class in your view when defining 'serializer_class' attribute